# If $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $f(x)= \begin{cases} {g(x)} & {x\ge k} \\ {g'(x)} & {x< k} \end{cases} $ , $\max (k)=?$ if $f$ is a differentiable function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

> If $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $f(x)= \begin{cases} {g(x)} & {x\ge k} \\
>  {g'(x)} & {x< k} \end{cases}  $. If $f(x)$ is a differentiable
> function, what is the maximum value of $k$, provided that $b+c=a$?
>
> $1)\frac34\qquad\qquad2)1\qquad\qquad3)3\qquad\qquad4)4$

In order to $f(x)$ be differentiable function, we should have $g(k)=g'(k)=g''(k)$,

$$ak^2+bk+c=2ak+b=2a$$  $$(b+c)k^2+bk+c=(2b+2c)k+b=2b+2c$$
Here for each equation I tried to equate the coefficients of $k^2 , k^1 , k^0$ but I get $a=b=c=0$ which doesn't make sense at all. I don't know how to continue form here.

Comment: There is no absolute  bound on $k$ without further assumptions on $a,b,c$.  The question is wrong.

Comment: Equating the coefficients of $k^2, k^1, k^0$ is valid if the equation must hold for all real $k$, or at least for three different values of $k$. But you're just looking for the case where one particular value of $k$ makes it true.

Comment: I agree with geetha290km. $a=b=c=0$ perfectly makes sense. In that case,  $f=0$ for any $k$, hence $k$ has no maximum value. To make the question "right", you have to exclude explicitely this case.

Comment: @geetha290krm Does assuming $b+c\neq 0$ make the question correct or we need more restrictions on $a,b,c$?

Comment: Assuming that $a\neq 0$ is enough to make the question technically ok. however, this looks like a school exercise or maybe some exam question and I think the non-standard and quite misleading wording is counterproductive in an educational setting. A much better formulation imho would be 'What condition do the numbers $a=b+c, b, c$ need to satisfy such that the value of the constant $k$ ensuring differentiability of $f$ is maximized? What is the value of $k$?'

Comment: @AnCar Thanks! Yes, it was taken from a university entrance exam.

Comment: And unfortunately most of the math books and school teachers in my country don't care about rigorous mathematics. They mostly teach formulas and tricks to solve problems quickly to prepare students for the exam! And this is a problem from the exam itself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A solution with no square roots needed.)

$g'(k) = g''(k)$ gives

$$ 2ak+b = 2a $$

If $a=0$ then this forces $b=0$, $0 = g'(k) = 2a$ so $a=0$, and finally $g(k)=c=0$. In the degenerate case where $f$ and $g$ are zero everywhere, $k$ can be any number at all. The problem should have eliminated this case, to have an answer.

So for the rest, assume $a \neq 0$.

$$ k = 1 - \frac{b}{2a} $$

Then $g(k) = g''(k)$ gives

$$ a\left(1 - \frac{b}{a} + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right) + b\left(1-\frac{b}{2a}\right) + c = 2a $$
$$ a + c - \frac{b^2}{4a} = 2a $$

Substituting $c=a-b$,

$$ \frac{b^2}{4a} + b = 0 $$

So either $b=0$ or $\frac{b}{a} = -4$. If $b=0$, $k=1$. If $\frac{b}{a} = -4$, $k=3$. The largest possible value of $k$ (again excluding the $a=b=c=0$ case) is $k=3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x) = (b + c)x^2 + bx + c$$
$$g'(x) = 2(b + c)x + b$$
$$g''(x) = 2(b + c)$$

For $f$ to be *continuous* at $k$, we must have $g(k) = g'(k)$,

$$(b + c)k^2 + bk + c = 2(b + c)k + b$$
$$(b + c)k^2 + (- b - 2c)k + (c - b) = 0$$
$$k = \frac{b + 2c \pm \sqrt{(-b-2c)^2 - 4(b+c)(c-b)}}{2(b+c)}$$
$$k = \frac{b + 2c \pm \sqrt{5b^2+4bc}}{2(b+c)}$$

For $f$ to be *differentiable* at $k$, we must have $g'(k) = g''(k)$.

$$2(b + c)k + b = 2(b + c)$$
$$2(b + c)k = b + 2c$$
$$k = \frac{b + 2c}{2(b + c)}$$

Equating the two expressions for $k$ gives:

$$\frac{b + 2c \pm \sqrt{5b^2+4bc}}{2(b+c)} = \frac{b + 2c}{2(b + c)}$$
$$b + 2c \pm \sqrt{5b^2+4bc} = b + 2c$$
$$\pm \sqrt{5b^2+4bc} = 0$$
$$5b^2+4bc = 0$$
$$b(5b+4c) = 0$$
$$b = 0 \text{ or } b = -\frac{4c}{5}$$

If $b = 0$, then $k = \frac{2c}{2c} = 1$.

If $b = -\frac{4c}{5}$, then $k = \frac{-\frac{4c}{5} + 2c}{2(-\frac{4c}{5} + c)} = \frac{1.2c}{0.4c} = 3$.

So $k \in \{ 1, 3 \}$.  The maximum value in this set is 3.

Comment: If $b = -4c/5$ then $k=3$.

Answer (score 1):

The original question looks wrong or at least badly worded. From continuity and differentiability at $k$, one indeed gets $g(k)=g'(k)=g''(k)$.

First assume that $a\neq 0$ and therefore $b+c\neq 0$.

Solving the differentiability condition gives $k=1-\frac{b}{2a}=\frac{b+2c}{2b+2c}$, using $b+c=a$.

The continuity condition gives the degree two equation in $k$, $(b+c)k^2 -(b+2c)k+c-b=0$, with discriminant $\Delta=5b^2+4bc$. The solutions are $k_{1,2}=\frac{b+2c\pm \sqrt{5b^2+4bc}}{2b+2c}$.

Comparing the two conditions, assuming $b+c\neq 0$, the only way a $k$ can exist is if $5b^2+4bc=0$, i.e., $b=0$ or $c=-\frac{5b}{4}$.

If $b=0$, then the unique solution is $k=1-\frac{0}{2a}=1$.

If $c=-\frac{5b}{4}$, then again there is a unique solution $k=\frac{b-\frac{5b}{2}}{2(b-\frac{5b}{4})}=3$.

Finally, if $a=b+c=0$, then $g(x)=bx-b$ and the differentiability and continuity condition boils down to $bk-b=b=0$, so $f$ is differentiable if and only if $g\equiv0$. And then clearly any $k$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a\neq 0$:

Statement 1:
$$ak^2+bk+c=2ak+b$$
$$ak^2+(b-2a)k+(c-b)=0$$
$$k=\frac{2a-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ab+4a^2+4ab-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$k=\frac{2a-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Statement 2:
$$2ak+b=2a$$
$$k=\frac{2a-b}{2a}$$
Statement 3, combining 1 and 2:
$$\frac{2a-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{2a-b}{2a}$$
$$2a-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a^2-4ac}=2a-b$$
$$\sqrt{b^2+4a^2-4ac}=0$$
$$b^2+4a^2-4ac=0$$
Substituting $b=a-c$:
$$a^2-2ac+c^2+4a^2-4ac=0$$
$$5a^2-6ac+c^2=0$$
$$a=\frac{6c\pm\sqrt{36c^2-20c^2}}{10}$$
$$a=\frac{6c\pm4c}{10}$$
This gives two solutions, $a_+=c, a_-=\frac c5$

Then, $b_+=0, b_-=-\frac{4c}5$

We then solve using each of these values:

For $+$, we can substitute into statement $2$ and get that $k=1$, and the solution $g(x)=ax^2+a$ results in $f(x)$ being continuous and differentiable everywhere and satisfies $b+c=a$

For $-$, we substitute into statement $2$ and get that $k=1+\frac45c=1+4a$.  This gives us $g(x)=ax^2-4ax+5a, g'(x)=2ax-4a, g''(x)=2a$. As such, $g(k)=16a^3-8a^2+2a$, $g'(k)=8a^2-2a$, $g''(k)=2a$.  Solving $g'(k)=g''(x)$ gives $-a^2=\frac a2$, or possible solutions of $a=0$ and $a=\frac12$.  As we assumed $a\neq 0$, we have that $a=\frac 12$, which can easily be verified is also a solution for $g(k)=g'(k)$.  We then have $k=3$ and $g(x)=\frac 12 x^2 -2x+\frac 52$, which results in $f(x)$ being continuous and differentiable everywhere and satisfies $b+c=a$

Lastly, consider what if $a=0$.  In this case, $g(x)=bx+c$ and $g''(x)=0$, which means that in order for $f$ to be differentiable, $g'(k)=0$.  This means that $b=0$, and  therefore $g(x)=c$.  In order for $f$ to be continuous, this means that $c=0$ as well.

In answer to the question, if we allow $g(x)$ to be $0$ everywhere, then there is no maximum value of $k$ that makes $f$ differentiable everywhere.  If we restrict that there must be some value of $x$ for which $g(x)\neq0$, we
found two solutions for $g(x)$ and $k$ for which $f$ was continuous everywhere, and the greater value for $k$ was $3$

Answer (score 1):

Equating $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ and using $c=a-b$ gives
$$ax^2+x(b-2a)=2b-a.$$
Completing the square:
$$(2ax+b-2a)^2=4a(2b-a)+(b-2a)^2=b^2+4ab.$$
We must have only one solution, that is $b=0$ or $b=-4a$.  From $(2ax+b-2a)^2=0$ we get $x = 1$ or $x = 3$.